# Azure Speech SDK (C#) in Blazor (webasm) app - bug

Tags: c#, blazor, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I an trying to use the speech SDK in blazor webasm app, but with recurring problem of missing "Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll".

There are a few reports about this issue, but not single one relating to webasm app.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. new blazor webasm project in VS2019
   [sc1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGWZz.png)
   [sc2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc1QX.png)
2. Install Speech SDK package
   [sc3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faNbV.png)
3. Update Index.Razor with minimum code to reproduce

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

<h1>Bug Reproduction</h1>


@code {

    private static readonly string SpeechSubscriptionKey = "somevalidkey";
    private static readonly string SpeechLocation = "somelocation";

    private SpeechConfig _SpeechConfig;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        _SpeechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(SpeechSubscriptionKey, SpeechLocation);


    }
}
```

[sc4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGlOH.png)

4. Now, when build and run (no matter debug/release, clean/rebuild, publish etc.) will get you the console output:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
System.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(String subscriptionKey, String region)
```

The app page in the chrome opens, but the resource is indeed missing:
[sc5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGGVD.png)

As I mentioned, I found several reports about bugs related to this issue, but none of webasm target.
The only resolution I found mentioned was to manually copy the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll to the target directory.

I am not quite sure how to do that correctly for webasm project, as I am new to it (as well as to .net as a whole).

As an act of desperate man, I tried copying Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll to the folder \bin\Debug\net5.0\wwwroot_framework\ and updating blazor.boot.json. The dll will then appear in blazor-resources in chrome, but the error message is the same. (System.DllNotFoundException).

The problem is that I have no idea which of the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll files I can find in nuget\packages\microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech\1.14.0\ folder could work, if any.

I may be missing something important here, any help or explanation what goes on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why you want to use the SDK in the blazor application and not your own backend? It is unusual (not wrong). Especially, because you will explose the login data (e.g. the token) for the service, which could be misused by users of your system.

This doesn't solve your problem directly, but, maybe if you do the same things in your own API and let your blazor client (with a ```HttpClient``` ) interact with your API, it is safer way and you would get rid of the error.

Comment: Thanks, the plan was to create an app that's statically hostable on multiple tenant's environments, not relying on any framework. The app should access client microphones, which is easy to do with this SDK. I get that the credentials for speech service cannot be exposed in the code just like it is in the example, but that's another thing. The code above is just to reproduce the problem I believe is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think your use case is a kind of an edge case, because Blazor itself doesn't let you access things like microphone or camera. You have to built js interop service for that. However, there is a Javascript library for the Azure Speech SDK. You could just it and built the wrapper for Blazor?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that WASM target is not yet supported. Js-sdk is the option for the time being. [github issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/930)